# Faster way to convert triangle list to edge list with no duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a list of triangles returned by a Delaunay triangulator, in the following format:

```
triangles = {{1, 7, 9}, {11, 9, 5}, {1, 9, 6}, {6, 11, 4}, {11, 6, 9}, 
             {4, 11, 8}, {9, 7, 13}, {5, 13, 10}, {13, 5, 9}, {2, 13, 7}, 
             {13, 2, 10}, {8, 12, 3}, {12, 8, 5}, {10, 3, 12}, {12, 5, 10}, {5, 8, 11}}
```

The integers are point indices.  I need to convert this triangle list into an edge list which has no duplicate edges.   For example, the first triangle from the list has these three edges: `{{1,7}, {7,9}, {9,1}}`.  My first naive approach was this:

```
trianglesToLines[tri_] := 
  Union[Sort /@ Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ tri, 1]]
```

This is not fast enough, unfortunately, so I came up with this ugly compiled alternative:

```
cf = Compile[{{tri, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{i, res},
   res = Table[0, {2 Length[tri]}];
   Do[
    res[[6 i + 1]] = tri[[3 i + 1]];
    res[[6 i + 2]] = tri[[3 i + 2]];
    res[[6 i + 3]] = tri[[3 i + 2]];
    res[[6 i + 4]] = tri[[3 i + 3]];
    res[[6 i + 5]] = tri[[3 i + 1]];
    res[[6 i + 6]] = tri[[3 i + 3]];,
    {i, 0, Length[tri]/3 - 1}];
   res
   ]
  ]

trianglesToLines2[tri_] := Union@Partition[cf@Flatten[Sort /@ tri], 2]
```

This is much faster but awfully ugly.  Is there a better way to speed up the operation?  I will accept an answer that is a bit slower than the compiled one if it is considerably more elegant.

---

Timings on my machine:

```
In[203]:= trianglesToLines[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[203]= {1.302468, Null}

In[204]:= trianglesToLines2[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming
Out[204]= {0.206924, Null}
```

Test data:

```
triangles = Import["http://ge.tt/api/1/files/4ulWlnb/0/blob?download", "WDX"];
```

---

#### Summary and timings

The fastest solution on a single core was Simon Woods's one.  R.M.'s is just as fast when run on 4 cores.  I included both a parallelized and a non-parallel version of R.M.'s function, as well as a Simon's with parallelized `Sort`.

```
(* original *)

trianglesToLines[tri_] := 
 Union[Sort /@ Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ tri, 1]]

(* original compiled *)

cf = Compile[{{tri, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Module[{i, res}, res = Table[0, {2 Length[tri]}];
    Do[res[[6 i + 1]] = tri[[3 i + 1]];
     res[[6 i + 2]] = tri[[3 i + 2]];
     res[[6 i + 3]] = tri[[3 i + 2]];
     res[[6 i + 4]] = tri[[3 i + 3]];
     res[[6 i + 5]] = tri[[3 i + 1]];
     res[[6 i + 6]] = tri[[3 i + 3]];, {i, 0, Length[tri]/3 - 1}];
    res]];

trianglesToLines2[tri_] := Union@Partition[cf@Flatten[Sort /@ tri], 2]

(* einbandi *)

trianglesToLines3[tri_] := 
 Union@(Sort /@ 
    Flatten[Function[x, x[[#]] & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}] /@ tri, 
     1])

(* R.M. *)
With[{part = Compile`GetElement, 
   e = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}}}, 
  cfrm = Compile[{{tri, _Integer, 1}}, 
    With[{t = Sort@tri}, Map[part[t, #] &, e, {2}]], 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    Parallelization -> False]];

trianglesToLinesRM[tri_] := Union[cfrm@tri~Flatten~1]

(* R.M. parallel *)

With[{part = Compile`GetElement, e = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}}}, 
  cfrmp = Compile[{{tri, _Integer, 1}}, 
    With[{t = Sort@tri}, Map[part[t, #] &, e, {2}]], 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    Parallelization -> True]];

trianglesToLinesRMp[tri_] := Union[cfrmp@tri~Flatten~1]

(* Simon Woods *)

trianglesToLinesSW[t_] := 
 Union@Flatten[{{#1, #2}, {#2, #3}, {#1, #3}} & @@ 
    Transpose[Sort /@ t], {{1, 3}, {2}}]

(* Simon Woods; parallel Sort *)

cs = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}}, Sort[x], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];

trianglesToLinesSWp[t_] := 
 Union@Flatten[{{#1, #2}, {#2, #3}, {#1, #3}} & @@ 
    Transpose[cs[t]], {{1, 3}, {2}}]
```

**Timings on OS X**, quad-core i7 processor with hyperthreading:

```
In[13]:= (* original *)
trianglesToLines[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[13]= {1.075996, Null}

In[14]:= (* original compiled *)    
trianglesToLines2[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[14]= {0.208128, Null}

In[15]:= (* einbandi *)
trianglesToLines3[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[15]= {0.397399, Null}

In[16]:= (* R.M. *)
trianglesToLinesRM[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[16]= {0.261082, Null}

In[17]:= (* R.M. parallel *)    
trianglesToLinesRMp[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[17]= {0.136793, Null}

In[18]:= (* Simon Woods *)    
trianglesToLinesSW[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[18]= {0.146266, Null}

In[19]:= (* Simon Woods; parallel sort *)    
trianglesToLinesSWp[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[19]= {0.111575, Null}
```

**Timings on Ubuntu 13.04** running on the same machine in VirtualBox with two assigned CPU cores.  Note that all solutions run considerably faster (except the parallelized ones).

```
In[13]:= (*original*)
trianglesToLines[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[13]= {0.869539, Null}

In[14]:= (*original compiled*)
trianglesToLines2[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[14]= {0.188039, Null}

In[15]:= (*einbandi*)
trianglesToLines3[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[15]= {0.317713, Null}

In[16]:= (*R.M.*)
trianglesToLinesRM[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[16]= {0.197207, Null}

In[17]:= (*R.M.parallel*)
trianglesToLinesRMp[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[17]= {0.150842, Null}

In[18]:= (*Simon Woods*)
trianglesToLinesSW[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[18]= {0.119471, Null}

In[19]:= (*Simon Woods;parallel sort*)
trianglesToLinesSWp[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[19]= {0.111481, Null}
```

Comment: The built-in function `Subsets` is exactly the function you describe

`Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ triangles; // AbsoluteTiming`

`{0.468339, Null}`

Not sure if this can be tweaked for speed.

Comment: @Cameron You're right, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a version with decent performance without `Compile`. The idea is to `Transpose` the data so that the vertex lists `{{a,b},{b,c},{a,c}}` can be created in one go instead of mapping over the list. The posh version of `Flatten` is used to reshape the list afterwards.

```
trianglesToLinesSW[t_] := 
 Union@Flatten[{{#1, #2}, {#2, #3}, {#1, #3}} & @@ Transpose[Sort /@ t], {{1, 3}, {2}}]
```

Comment: This runs in the same time as RM's but without parallelization, which makes it the fastest solution so far.

Comment: A nice mastery of list manipulation demonstrated here. +1

Comment: The output doesn't seem exactly correct. The triangle edges are not groups into a list.

Comment: I guess it really is time to learn how to use that form of `Flatten`. An interesting twist with your method is that `Apply` unpacks, but it doesn't seem to matter. Switching to `{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, {#[[2]], #[[3]]}, {#[[1]], #[[3]]}}& @` takes practically the same time. +1

Answer (score 4):

By moving the sorting operation inside `Compile` and doing it only once per triangle instead of 3 as in your code (by indexing in the right order), I could get it to be twice as fast as your compiled solution and is considerably cleaner in my opinion:

```
With[{part = Compile`GetElement, e = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}}},
    cfrm = Compile[{{tri, _Integer, 1}},
        With[{t = Sort@tri}, Map[part[t, #] &, e, {2}]], 
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
    ]
];

trianglesToLinesRM[tri_] := Union[cfrm@tri ~Flatten~ 1]
```

You can add `CompilationTarget -> "C"` for a slight increase in speed. Timings on my machine:

```
res1 = trianglesToLinesSZ[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.217710, Null} *)

res2 = trianglesToLinesRM[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.129866, Null} *)

res1 == res2 
(* True *)
```

Comment: This is faster than my compiled version only when it can run in parallel, it seems.  I tried this by running it in VirtualBox with 1 CPU assigned (there surely must be a better way, but this was simple).  A very weird thing I noticed is that *all* solutions run considerable faster in VirtualBox on Linux, than on OS X (except yours, but that's only because I can't assign it all 8 cores).  For example my first approach runs in 0.8 on Linux while it runs in 1.2 on OS X ...  I'll accept tomorrow if there are no faster ones :-)

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, this takes about twice as much time as your compiled version (but is about three times faster than your first version):

```
trianglesToLines3[tri_] := Union@(Sort /@ Flatten[
     Function[x, x[[#]] & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}] /@ tri,
     1])
```

Some timings:

```
trianglesToLines[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming
trianglesToLines2[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming
trianglesToLines3[triangles]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*    
{2.9401405, Null}
{0.5510264, Null}
{1.0140485, Null}
*)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did too :) Mine's twice as fast as Szabolcs's. Re: sorting, what I did was to sort the integers in each triangle list and ensure that the indexing did not change the ordering, which means that the last indexing element becomes `{1,3}`

Comment: Funny. :) It's basically the first approach that I tried. I don't really know a lot about `Compile`  though, so I just left it as it is. And it looks quite nice and clean in my opinion.

Comment: btw, looking at your timing results, I should consider buying a new computer :)

Comment: The `Sort` before `Union` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `Union` already sorts the results, that should be sufficient.

Comment: Yup, I removed the redundant `Sort`.

Answer (score 2):

slight variation, maybe a little more elegant. I dont have the full data set to check timing.

```
Union@Flatten[Sort /@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ triangles, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `Subsets` does this using the second option `{2}` for subsets containing exactly 2 elements?  With your test data I get

```
Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ triangles; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.468339, Null} *)
```

With exactly the output you describe

```
{{{9, 1}, {9, 129}, {1, 129}}, {{129, 246}, {129, 128}, {246, 
   128}}, {{15, 129}, {15, 1}, {129, 1}}, {{1, 13}, {1, 15}, {13, 
   15}},...
```

If anyone knows if speeds of built-in functions can be improved, I'd be very interested in some tips.

**EDIT**

Based on Simon Woods answer

```
{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, {#[[2]], #[[3]]}, {#[[1]], #[[3]]}} & /@ triangles; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.108670, Null} *)
```

Which seems like one of the fastest and simplest answers yet.  But apparently not the desired result.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. The requirement is for a list of all the edges in the whole triangulation, without any duplicates. So if the input data was `{{1,2,3}, {3,2,5}}` your code gives a total of six edges `{{{1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}}, {{3,2}, {2,5}, {3,5}}}`. But the edge `{3,2}` in the second triangle is a duplicate of the edge `{2,3}` in the first triangle. The desired output is a list of the *five* unique edges `{{1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {2,5}, {3,5}}`

Comment: Ah I see. No worries then.