# Treat list as cyclic

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions

I am considering the following case. Say that `T={p1,p2,p3}` represents a triangle. In addition, I want to parameterize the edges of the triangle `T`. What I currently do is:

```
edgesT = {
   t T[[1]] + (1 - t) T[[2]],
   t T[[2]] + (1 - t) T[[3]],
   t T[[3]] + (1 - t) T[[1]]};
```

This seems to be very naive, and I would like to learn how can I improve this. One, somehow obvious, way would be to have a cyclic list. Thus the question's title.

**Is there a (smart) way to treat a list as cyclic?**

Obviously, `T[[i]] = pi` for `i={1,2,3}`. It could be useful, for example in the example above, to enter `T[[4]]` and expect to have `p1` as an output. Is there some way to do it?

**If not, how can I improve the definition above?**

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21804/faster-way-to-convert-triangle-list-to-edge-list-with-no-duplicates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a nice function [`RotateLeft`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotateLeft.html):

```
edgesT[t_] := t T + (1 - t) RotateLeft[T];
```

Answer (score 5):

Getting the cyclic index is just a case of using `Mod` for instance: `T[[Mod[n, 3, 1]]]`. But as for making this simpler, I would suggest using a SubValue definition to get a `cyclicList` header which acts as though it was a cyclic list. This is accomplished through:

```
 cyclicList /: cyclicList[v__][[n_Integer]] := {v}[[Mod[n, Length@{v}, 1]]]

 T = cyclicList[p1, p2, p3];
 edgesT = Table[t T[[n]] + (1 - t) T[[n + 1]], {n, 3}]
```

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to treat a list as cyclic is `Partition`:

```
tri = {a, b, c};

edges = Partition[tri, 2, 1, 1] . {t, 1 - t}
(*  {b (1 - t) + a t, c (1 - t) + b t, a (1 - t) + c t} *)

tri2 = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}};
Transpose@Partition[tri2, 2, 1, 1].{t, 1 - t}

(* {{a2 (1 - t) + a1 t, b2 (1 - t) + b1 t, c2 (1 - t) + c1 t},
    {b2 (1 - t) + b1 t, c2 (1 - t) + c1 t, a2 (1 - t) + a1 t}} *)
```

Comment: This somehow doesn't work for me if I set `a={a1,a2}`, `b={b1,b2}` and `c={c1,c2} (such that they'll represent vertices).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Inner[t # + (1 - t) #2 &, T, RotateLeft@T, List]
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica already provides a build-in API to generate this kind of correlation.

```
ListCorrelate[{t, 1 - t}, {p1, p2, p3}, 2]
```

> {p1 (1 - t) + p3 t, p2 (1 - t) + p1 t, p3 (1 - t) + p2 t}